# Very simple way of submitting a form value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a few very simple forms on a page, all structured as below. I simply need to submit the form with the value when a link is pressed. Is there a way of submitting the value within the form that's clicked without having to uniquely id each form?

```
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementByName('id').submit();">
       some text with styling to click
    </a>
    </form>
```

Comment: You must have unique `name` or `id` to the form. There is no need to have `id`s to input elements

Comment: You can use a button instead, and style it like an anchor, then you won't need javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `.submit()` on `this.parentElement`

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentElement.submit();">
       some text with styling to click
    </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a button to submit the form, and style it however you'd like.
Buttons submit forms by default.

```css
button {
    background:none!important;
    border:none; 
    padding: 0;
    margin : 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <button>Button that submits the form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using jquery

```
$('form [name=myForm]').on('submit' function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: You catch the submit event, but you don't submit the form, if a link will be clicked in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think with jQuery this should work:

```
$('form a').click(function(e){
  var form = $(this).parent('form');
  form.submit();
  return false;
});
```

This way you find the links in a form and you add a click event to each of them. If a link is clicked you submit the surrounding form only. This is a solution for all of your forms. So you don't need to the `ugly` onClick to each link that blows up your code.

Without jQuery use: `this.parentElement.submit();` 
`this` is your link element and `parentElement`is the form you want to submit .

Comment: thank you - the non jQuery way has done the job nicely.

Comment: Your welcome - it's me, I love the more professional and clean way to code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do withtout jquery , just Give an Id to the form
copy the code below.

```
<form action="result.php" method="post" id='myForm'>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("myForm").submit();'>
       some text with styling to click
    </a>
    </form>
```

Comment: I used to have this to do the job but no longer want the image.<form action="player.php" method="post">
                                        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="767" />
                                        <input name="image" type="image" class="downloads_image" src="images/audiosymbol3.png" alt="speaker_symbol" onclick="this.form.select.value = this.value;" />
                                    </form>